# Create a row for a categorical values from categorical columns

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

this is my first question at StackOverflow. I hope that you can help with a problem, that is bothering me for some time. I couldn't find a answer that is fitting.

My data looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1},
               'col2': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3},
               'col3': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3},
               'col4': {0: 1.1, 1: 2.1, 2: 3.1},
               'col5': {0: 10, 1: 12, 2: 14},
               'col6': {0: 1.2, 1: 2.2, 2: 3.2},
               'col7': {0: 11, 1: 13, 2: 15},
              })
df.columns = ["VZ", "NZ", "L", "T_0_Rel", "T_0_Abs", "T_Akt_Rel", "T_Akt_Abs"]
df
```

which ouputs (without index-column):

```
╔════╦════╦═══╦═════════╦═════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╗
║ VZ ║ NZ ║ L ║ T_0_Rel ║ T_0_Abs ║ T_Akt_Rel ║ T_Akt_Abs ║
╠════╬════╬═══╬═════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
║  1 ║  1 ║ 1 ║   1.1   ║    10   ║    1.2    ║     11    ║
║  1 ║  1 ║ 2 ║   2.1   ║    12   ║    2.2    ║     13    ║
║  1 ║  1 ║ 3 ║   3.1   ║    14   ║    3.2    ║     15    ║
╚════╩════╩═══╩═════════╩═════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╝
```

Now I want to twist this DataFrame into something like this:

```
╔════╦════╦═══╦═════════════╦═════╦═════╗
║ VZ ║ NZ ║ L ║ T_0 / T_Akt ║ Abs ║ Rel ║
╠════╬════╬═══╬═════════════╬═════╬═════╣
║  1 ║  1 ║ 1 ║     T_0     ║ 10  ║ 1.1 ║
║  1 ║  1 ║ 1 ║     T_Akt   ║ 11  ║ 1.2 ║
║  1 ║  2 ║ 2 ║     T_0     ║ 12  ║ 2.1 ║
║  1 ║  2 ║ 2 ║     T_Akt   ║ 13  ║ 2.2 ║
║  1 ║  3 ║ 3 ║     T_0     ║ 14  ║ 3.1 ║
║  1 ║  3 ║ 3 ║     T_Akt   ║ 15  ║ 3.2 ║
╚════╩════╩═══╩═════════════╩═════╩═════╝
```

So basicly, I want a row for every T_O- and T_Akt-value, while the Abs- and Rel-values can stay in one row.

I supposed this should be possible with **.stack()** or **.melt()**, but I could figure out how to do it.

My intention behind all this is to have a categorical value in my DataFrame to use the **hue**-argument in the **seaborn.boxplot** or **.violinplot** function. I couldn't figure out how to use the hue-argument with several columns instead of a categorical value. 
(Maybe I am wrong here and there is a much easier way...)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you conceptually have a hierarchical column index, I would make it that way and then use `stack`

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'VZ': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1},
    'NZ': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3},
    'L': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3},
    'T_0_Rel': {0: 1.1, 1: 2.1, 2: 3.1},
    'T_0_Abs': {0: 10, 1: 12, 2: 14},
    'T_Akt_Rel': {0: 1.2, 1: 2.2, 2: 3.2},
    'T_Akt_Abs': {0: 11, 1: 13, 2: 15},
})

print(
    df.set_index(['VZ', 'NZ', 'L'])  # row labels
      .rename(columns=lambda c: tuple(c.rsplit('_', 1)))  # create the multi-cols
      .stack(level=0) # unpivot
      .reset_index()  # move the row labels back into normal columns 
)
```

And I see:

```
   VZ  NZ  L level_3  Abs  Rel
0   1   1  1     T_0   10  1.1
1   1   1  1   T_Akt   11  1.2
2   1   2  2     T_0   12  2.1
3   1   2  2   T_Akt   13  2.2
4   1   3  3     T_0   14  3.1
5   1   3  3   T_Akt   15  3.2
```